# Remotly create shares

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting

I need a script to create the same shared folder on 50 remote Windows Server 2003.

I have tried with psexec but havent got the syntax correct yet
psexec @c:\serverlist.txt cmd net share ShareName="e:\Share" /Remark:"Shared Folder" -d

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly call `net share` with `psexec` if you want to, but the [`rmtshare.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172599) utility would probably be the tool that I'd use.

In your command line you don't need the `cmd` and the `-d` (which is, presumably, a `psexec` argument) is in the wrong place. I think you're looking for `psexec @c:\serverlist.txt -d net share ShareName="e:\Share" /Remark:"Shared Folder"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [RMTSHARE.exe](http://www.dynawell.com/download/reskit/microsoft/win2000/rmtshare.zip) as well.  Give that you have a list of servers in serverlist.txt, I would run the following at a command prompt:

```
for /f %i in (c:\serverlist.txt) do RMTSHARE \\%i\ShareName=e:\share /Remark:"Shared Folder"
```

This will create a share named "ShareName" that is sharing e:\share with the remark "Shared Folder" and the default share permissions of Everyone: Read